Bent vectors and $\pm 1$ eigenvectors with respect to non-Sylvester Hadamard matrices
A Hadamard matrix is an $n\times n$-matrix $H$ where each entry in $H$ is $\pm 1$ and where $H/\sqrt{n}$ is orthogonal. It is well-known that if $H$ is an $n\times n$-Hadamard matrix, then $n<3$ or $n$ is a multiple of $4$.
We say that a vector $v$ is a bent vector with respect to the $n\times n$-Hadamard matrix $H$ if each entry in $v$ and also in $(H/\sqrt{n})v$ is $\pm 1$. If $v$ is a bent vector with respect to $H$, then $n$ must be a perfect square.
Bent vectors are closely related to $\pm 1$-eigenvectors. If $v$ is a $\pm 1$-eigenvector for a Hadamard matrix $H$, then $v$ necessarily corresponds to a real eigenvalue, and this real eigenvalue must be $\pm\sqrt{n}$, so since $v=(H/\sqrt{n})v$, $v$ is also a bent vector. Conversely, if $v$ is a bent vector, then there is a diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal entries $\pm 1$ with $v=D(H/\sqrt{n})v$. In this case, $DH$ is also a Hadamard matrix and $v$ is a $\pm 1$ eigenvector for $DH$ with eigenvalue $\sqrt{n}$.
Let $S=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$ Then the tensor power $S^{\otimes n}$ (the tensor power is defined by setting $S^{\otimes 1}=S,S^{\otimes(n+1)}=S^{\otimes s}\otimes S$) is a $2^n\times 2^n$-Hadamard matrix known as the Sylvester construction of a Hadamard matrix. There are a few ways of trivially transforming a Hadamard matrix into another one. We say that two Hadamard matrices are equivalent if one can be transformed into the other by composing the operations of taking the transpose, swapping rows, swapping columns, and multiplying a row or column by $-1$.
What are some ways to construct bent vectors and $\pm 1$-eigenvectors for Hadamard matrices that are not equivalent to the Sylvester construction?
Bent vectors with respect to the Sylvester construction of Hadamard matrices are useful in cryptography, and there are a lot of these bent vectors. I have tried to construct a bent vector (using some heuristic algorithms) with respect to one of these non-Sylvester Hadamard matrices, but I was unable to produce such a vector.

This paper seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16439, they have a github repository here https://github.com/Qomo-CHENG/Hadamard_bent
